# How do I fix this? linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sdk, vundle

I am adding Vungle SDK to my objective C project and I keep getting this error which I cannot figure out

[image]

Does anybody have any clues on how to fix this issue?

I am also using Cocoa pods!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add VungleSDK just before this error occured. Or did any other action related to the Xcode project happen before?

Comment: @M_G This error occurred after I added Vungle iOS SDK

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/) to add the SDK to your project. This way you do not have to worry about manual Xcode setup.

See https://support.vungle.com/hc/en-us/articles/204430550-Get-Started-with-Vungle-iOS-SDK

Comment: That's a fantastic point (and +1 to you for suggesting it), but I wonder if the O.P. is using Cocoapods (since it wasn't mentioned in the question) or knows what to do with it.

Comment: Hey Guys thanks for the help. I am using cocoa pods and I am still having this issue!

Comment: Just to be sure. Did you open the workspace or the project file? @MichaelDautermann Thanks

Comment: any other solutions?

Comment: I set up a sample project with Vungle as single dependency via Cocoapods and the project build without problems. Lucky shot: Maybe you could remove the dependency, build and add it again afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things you need to do:

1)  in the list of files in your Xcode project, click on the framework and makes sure it's included in your target.  Like I've done with RNCryptor in my own project here:
[image: Check Target Membeship]
2)  Go to your Target's Build Phases and make sure your framework is included under "Link Binary With Libraries"
[image: Link Binary With Libraries]

Separately, IF you are using Cocoapods:

1) make sure to do both a `pod install` and `pod update` (while the Xcode workspace is closed) and once that's done, reopen the workspace.

Comment: I tried doing it this way also and I still have the same problem

Comment: it would have been nice if you had mentioned Cocopods in the original question.  Can you edit your question to show the contents of your Podfile?

Answer (score 0):

So many different problems for the same error message.(Linker command failed with exit code 1)

**1)** if you had two same constants in different classes then also this issue happens.

**2)** if you have accidentally imported a `.m` file instead of `.h` file in an implementation file.

**3)** This error can also be occurred if you have imported two different versions of same library ,in this case just remove the older version and keep only one version.

**4)** Adding the "`other linker flags`" in "`Project`" and not in "`Targets`". So, you move it to "`Targets`", it shouldn't be in "`Project`".

**5)** Check it out in

```
project->target->build settings-> search enable bitcode->set NO in DEBUG
```

check out this .. if it's OK then once do like following.

`Menu > Product > Clean` ... then Run the project

I think after `deleting` Derived data, `cleaning` and `rebuilding` will works fine. One more thing, you need to split code of `AppDelegate` and `ViewController` cause they have their own roles.

Hope it helps you.. :)